# less: filter out pattern passed as command line argument + follow file via bash function

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a bash function that will use `less` to apply a pattern and follow the file using the argument passed to the function

```
my_less_function() {
        if [ -z "$1" ]
        then
                # if no arg
                less +F /var/log/my.log
        else
                # else, filter out the arg
                less +$'&!'$1'\nF' /var/log/my.log
        fi
}
```

my issue is that i can't get the arg to substitute properly in the else block

`my_less_function MY_VALUE` displays `Non-match &/MY_VALUE\nF` in less

it looks like it's concatenating the argument and `\nF`, but `\nF` is supposed to trigger the follow command instead of being interpreted as part of the argument

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong : `less +$'&!'$1'\nF' /var/log/my.log`

---

right : `less +$'&!'${1}$'\nF' /var/log/my.log`